# How do you add const to the pointed-to type?

Tags: c++, templates, constants, type-traits, const-correctness

Say I have a class template:

```
template <class T>
struct A
{
  T value;

  void foo(auto fun) { 
    fun(value);
    // ^^^^^^^ Pass value as a const object
  }
};
```

I want to add const to the `value`, when calling `fun` **so that only functions that accept** `T`, `T const&`, `T const*` are callable. My initial approach was to make `foo` a const member function, but this fails for reference and pointer members, since const member functions can modify them (you just cannot rebase those members).

I also try to use `std::add_const` and `std::as_const` to pass the value to the argument function (`fun`) but this makes a transformation like the following:

```
T = MyData*                  // say T is the type "Pointer to MyData"
add_const<T> = MyData *const // constness is added to the pointer, 
                             // i.e. it becomes constant pointer to MyData
```

The target type I'd like to have in the example above is `MyData const*` (pointer to constant `MyData`).

- Is there a standard facility to achieve this?
- Is there a different way to do it, I mean other than decorating the call `fun(value)`?

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/95672e449f037679)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can

```cpp
using target_type = std::conditional_t<std::is_pointer_v<T>,
                                       std::remove_pointer_t<T> const*,
                                       T const>;
fun(static_cast<target_type>(value));
```

Then when `T` is `MyData*`, the converted type would be `MyData const*`; for non-pointer type like `MyData` the converted type would be `MyData const`.

Comment: Plugged the extension in the Demo, and it bans the call I wanted to ban, nice. This is reminiscent of the const_iterator type problem, I thought the Standard library would have some facility to cover it

Comment: @lorah it does not, because your solution is a patch over a design bug.  Treating foo and foo pointers uniformly is code smell.  But you'll survive